# Помогите решать задачу через регулярные выражения на java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Натыкал немного кода. Не понимаю, что не так. Подсвечивает одно из условий желтым. Пожалуйста, не опускайте вопрос. Правда помощь нужна, мне сегодня нужно задачу сдать.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    String text = "go to ABC electro 77";
    String[] parts = text.split("[,;:\\s+]");
    for (String  p : parts){
        System.out.print("["+ p +"],");
    }
    System.out.println();
    int counter = 0;

    for (String  p : parts){
        if ((p.length() <= 6) && (p.length() >= 2) && (p.contains("[^a-z]")) && (p.contains("[^0-9]")) && (p.contains("[A-Z]"))){
            counter++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

}

[image: условие]
[image: Задача]
В универе дали задачу, нужно решить через регулярные выражения. Я отдаленно понимаю как, но просто времени нет.

Answer (score 0):

`String::contains` НЕ использует регулярные выражения, он проверяет вхождение подстроки в строку, поэтому и получается предупреждение об *излишней* проверке длины строки на 2 и больше, так как подстроки-аргументы в `contains` имеют длину 6 и 5 символов.

В вашем подходе достаточно заменить `String::contains` на `String::matches` с регулярным выражением `[A-ZА-ЯЁ]{2,6}`, проверяющим сразу ограничение на минимальную и максимальную длину:

```java
for (String  p : parts) {
    if (p.matches("[A-ZА-ЯЁ]{2,6}")) {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

---

Похожее решение с использованием Stream API, реализованное в виде отдельной функции, возвращающей список аббревиатур:

```java
public static List<String> getAbbrevs(String str) {
    return Arrays.stream(str.split("[\\p{Z}\\p{P}]+"))
        .filter(s -> s.matches("\\p{Lu}{2,6}"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Также здесь используются [Unicode-категории](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html):

- `p{Z}` - любые пробельные символы, включая невидимые
- `p{P}` - любые символы пунктуации
- `p{Lu}` - любые прописные буквы (не только английские и русские)

Тест:

```java
String text = "go to ABC electro 77 I am MUZzY IQ Ok КТО Здесь? ЗДРАСТЕ";

System.out.println(getAbbrevs(text));

// -> [ABC, IQ, КТО]
```